# Align text when next to icons or spans with unicode characters

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a list of posts as given below using plain css and html.

If u look closely the texts of the headings appear to be slanted when next to an icon badges which I have made using Unicode characters and also a font awesome Unicode character.

Why do the text next to icons appear slanted is there a way to fix this ?

I have tried using flex box technique to no avail.

```css
.post {
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 1rem 0.1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.profile_pic {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.post_content {
  flex: 9;
  position: relative;
}

.avatar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FC5C7D;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #6A82FB, #FC5C7D);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6A82FB, #FC5C7D);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
}

.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.6rem;
  height: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* .main_title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
} */

.main_title .heading {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  margin-left: 0.8rem;
  color:
}

.star_badge {
  background: #E68E8E;
}

.tick_badge {
  background: #ECD7A8;
}

.star_badge::after {
  content: '\2605';
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.tick_badge::after {
  content: '\2714';
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.reply {
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
}

.reply::after {
  content: "\f3e5";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.username {
  color: #BEB4BC;
}

.timestamp {
  color: #BEB4BC;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.excerpt {
  color: #BEB4BC;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.statscat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
}

.statscat span:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.replies {
  color: #BEB4BC;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.replies::before {
  content: "\f27a";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-right: 1.4rem;
}

.views {
  color: #BEB4BC;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.views::before {
  content: "\f06e";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-right: 1.4rem;
}

.category {
  color: white;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.8rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="posts">

  <div class="post">
    <div class="profile_pic">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_content">
      <div class="main_title">
        <a class="star_badge badge"></a>
        <a class="tick_badge badge"></a>
        <span class="heading">
                Will this forum be beneficial
              </span>
      </div>
      <div class="user_details">
        <span class="reply"></span>
        <span class="username">Minded</span>
        <span class="timestamp">replied 4 hours ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="excerpt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem placeat voluptas itaque ipsa quasi porro sit perferendis, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, ipsam?
      </div>

      <div class="statscat">
        <span class="replies">11</span>
        <span class="views">89</span>
        <span class="category">Opinions</span>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="post">
    <div class="profile_pic">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_content">
      <div class="main_title">
        <a class="star_badge badge"></a>
        <a class="tick_badge badge"></a>
        <span class="heading">
                Will this forum be beneficial
              </span>
      </div>
      <div class="user_details">
        <span class="reply"></span>
        <span class="username">Minded</span>
        <span class="timestamp">replied 4 hours ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="excerpt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem placeat voluptas itaque ipsa quasi porro sit perferendis, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, ipsam?
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="statscat">
      <span class="replies">11</span>
      <span class="views">89</span>
      <span class="category">Opinions</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="post">
    <div class="profile_pic">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_content">
      <div class="main_title">
        <a class="star_badge badge"></a>
        <a class="tick_badge badge"></a>
        <span class="heading">
                Will this forum be beneficial
              </span>
      </div>
      <div class="user_details">
        <span class="reply"></span>
        <span class="username">Minded</span>
        <span class="timestamp">replied 4 hours ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="excerpt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem placeat voluptas itaque ipsa quasi porro sit perferendis, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, ipsam?
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="statscat">
      <span class="replies">11</span>
      <span class="views">89</span>
      <span class="category">Opinions</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="post">
    <div class="profile_pic">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_content">
      <div class="main_title">
        <a class="star_badge badge"></a>
        <a class="tick_badge badge"></a>
        <span class="heading">
                Will this forum be beneficial
              </span>
      </div>
      <div class="user_details">
        <span class="reply"></span>
        <span class="username">Minded</span>
        <span class="timestamp">replied 4 hours ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="excerpt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem placeat voluptas itaque ipsa quasi porro sit perferendis, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, ipsam?
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="statscat">
      <span class="replies">11</span>
      <span class="views">89</span>
      <span class="category">Opinions</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Also please see the output in full page.

[image]

Comment: I am not seeing the quoted behavior when I run this in Chrome...can you please add more clarification or detail perhaps?  I may not be looking at the right thing..

Comment: I tried in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. The header does not look slanted. Is this happening in any specific OS and/or browser?

Comment: Do you want to align the header text and imgs vertically?

Comment: please seen in full page.. checkout the border of each post entry and see the text relative to that you will find the text appear slanted.

Comment: @Sriram It is a bit difficult to see..you can see the excerpt appears slanted as well. I mean the whole text content not individual characters like it is the case in italics...

Comment: @UVic I checked in fullscreen and used on screen ruler. It does not appear slanted. Could it be due to your default browser font settings? Could you please try changing the browser default font or adding different font-family to the heading?

Comment: @Sriram I tried other browsers the problem persists.

Comment: @UVic Could you please provide the screenshot of it?

Comment: @Sriram I have updated the post....see the top excerpt relative to its bottom border..

Comment: @UVic I have put the screenshot with guides in the Answer section. As there is no provision to add or link the image in the comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the screenshot you have provided. Loaded the image in the editor and  used the guides to check if the headings appear to be slanted or not.

The headings and other texts and icons does not appear to be slanted. Only thing I see is comment, view and options elements in the second post aligned slightly on the top compared to the first post.

Below is the image with guides. Hope this helps.

[image]

I have modified the html code to fix the alignment issue. Below is the code

```
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="posts">

  <div class="post">
    <div class="profile_pic">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_content">
      <div class="main_title">
        <a class="star_badge badge"></a>
        <a class="tick_badge badge"></a>
        <span class="heading">
                Will this forum be beneficial
              </span>
      </div>
      <div class="user_details">
        <span class="reply"></span>
        <span class="username">Minded</span>
        <span class="timestamp">replied 4 hours ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="excerpt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem placeat voluptas itaque ipsa quasi porro sit perferendis, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, ipsam?
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="statscat">
        <span class="replies">11</span>
        <span class="views">89</span>
        <span class="category">Opinions</span>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="post">
    <div class="profile_pic">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_content">
      <div class="main_title">
        <a class="star_badge badge"></a>
        <a class="tick_badge badge"></a>
        <span class="heading">
                Will this forum be beneficial
              </span>
      </div>
      <div class="user_details">
        <span class="reply"></span>
        <span class="username">Minded</span>
        <span class="timestamp">replied 4 hours ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="excerpt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem placeat voluptas itaque ipsa quasi porro sit perferendis, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, ipsam?
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="statscat">
      <span class="replies">11</span>
      <span class="views">89</span>
      <span class="category">Opinions</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="post">
    <div class="profile_pic">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_content">
      <div class="main_title">
        <a class="star_badge badge"></a>
        <a class="tick_badge badge"></a>
        <span class="heading">
                Will this forum be beneficial
              </span>
      </div>
      <div class="user_details">
        <span class="reply"></span>
        <span class="username">Minded</span>
        <span class="timestamp">replied 4 hours ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="excerpt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem placeat voluptas itaque ipsa quasi porro sit perferendis, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, ipsam?
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="statscat">
      <span class="replies">11</span>
      <span class="views">89</span>
      <span class="category">Opinions</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="post">
    <div class="profile_pic">
      <div class="avatar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_content">
      <div class="main_title">
        <a class="star_badge badge"></a>
        <a class="tick_badge badge"></a>
        <span class="heading">
                Will this forum be beneficial
              </span>
      </div>
      <div class="user_details">
        <span class="reply"></span>
        <span class="username">Minded</span>
        <span class="timestamp">replied 4 hours ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class="excerpt">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem placeat voluptas itaque ipsa quasi porro sit perferendis, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, ipsam?
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="statscat">
      <span class="replies">11</span>
      <span class="views">89</span>
      <span class="category">Opinions</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do I fix it ?

Comment: @UVic Closing div is missing for the first 'div class="post_content"'. So add the closing div before first 'div class="statscat"'. I have tested this and the alignment is fixed. I have updated the answer with the code.